# Users get In-App products without paying, Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have 3 non-consumable IAP products in my app. I use Store Kit to handle them. 
Recently, I have added a custom event to get notified immediately once a user buys one. Also, I am creating an entry in my database. 
All this code and events are in ".purchased" case of my paymentQueue function.

The problem is; I see a few users can manage to trigger my event and DBwrite function and I cannot see them in Sales report or Firebase default (built-in, not custom) "in_app purchase" event.

If they can trigger my IAP event, they get all the features for free.

I use observers separately for each product. Every time user sees the product page, I add that View Controller as an observer and when they close that View Controller I remove the observer.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: They might be restoring a previous purchase

Comment: My DBwrite and custom event code is on ".purchased" case only, not in ".restored" case.

Comment: You should validate the receipt through a server if you want better protection against IAP fraud.

Comment: So, do you think that it is a form of fraud?

Comment: It could be. It could also be a re-presentation of a transaction that could not be completed for some reason in the first try.

Comment: It might be a refund situation. If Apple refunds the user, the in-app feature will continue to work.

Comment: Actually, these all happen when user buys for the first time. In firebase console It seems there are 3 events triggered by one unique user but different regions. Iran is always there, maybe this might be about VPN?